Does MO theory show delocalized electrons
Does the MO theory deem the pi MO delocalized in systems with delocalized electrons like nitrate, benzene and ozone

No, as its name says, it uses molecular orbitals. Check for example Why is the resonance concept not required in molecular orbital theory?.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33879/what-is-actually-the-difference-between-valence-bond-theory-and-molecular-orbita https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68472/do-mos-span-a-bond-or-the-whole-molecule

No not like resonance structures but like When describing for example nitrate, does it do MO diagram of one of its resonance structures or does the MO diagram of nitrate describe nitrate structure where electrons are delocalized across a model that is average of all resonance structures (Resonance hybrid theory)

Or Does it just describe sommething entirely different more accurate than both theories

Resonance structures are completely irrelevant to MOT. There are MOs of molecules not some resonance structures.

For example Nitrate has a hybrid resonance structure where pi electrons of O and N aren't forming double bond but rather are delocalized like in benzene. In benzene, p orbital electrons of Carbons don't form double bonds but create a delocalized ring in center. Does MO along with antibonding and bonding orbitals represent delocalized pi electrons in benzene or nitrate or does it do something different

Hiya user154560, I believe it sounds like we're honing in on what your question really is:  Does MO theory describe how the de-localized electrons in resonance structures?  This question, feels answered similar to @Mithoron's first comment.

E.g I have seen video saying p orbitals have a bonding interaction in benzene as they are on the same plane so we can represent it as a uniformly delocalized pi bonding molecular orbital cloud above and below the ring. Is this true or false. Does the MO theory then agree with delocalized ring in benzene

You are looking at things the wrong way around. MO theory finds the orbitals for the electrons in the electric field of the nuclei. There is in principle in MO theory no reference to the original atomic orbitals of the atoms in the molecule, you simply get a set of functions describing the electronic orbitals in the whole molecule. Such orbitals are a priori delocalised. As such the delocalisation in benzene or nitrate comes out naturally in MO theory, it is not hacked on as an after thought -  the results are simply the orbitals in the field of all the nuclei.

Now as humans and computationalists we need a way to express these functions, or at least visualise them. As chemists a natural way is to express this arbitrary functions as linear combinations of the atomic orbitals of the original atoms. This is called a basis, but it is not unique, and it is not a fundamental part of MO theory -it is merely a computational/visualisation tool to help us understand this arbitrary functions that are coming out of the theory. And there are many possible choices of basis, for instance in computations plane waves are also very commonly used.

So in summary you have it the wrong way round. In MO theory you get the delocalisation first, and then, optionally, can express that delocalisation as a sum of p orbitals. You don't dum up the p orbitals first and then declare delocalisation has occurred.

Does MO theory show delocalization in nitrate in like in benzene. I know like benzene, same theory for benzene's supposed delocalized ring states that nitrate ions have delocalized pi system. I can't provide an image but what I see looks similar to benzene's orbital diagram with delocalized pi system
